# Build app with iOS6 SDK for AppStore when iOS7 will released

Tags: ios6, xcode4, app-store, ios7, xcode5

I need to make some minor changes in app that already in AppStore. If I build app under iOS7 SDK then all UI elements have new look and new "layouting". For fix it I need a time. So my question is:

- Could I build app for AppStore under iOS6 SDK after iOS7 will released (Sept 18)?
- Should (and can) I use XCode 4 for posting to AppStore after iOS7 will released?
- Could I use XCode5 for build app for AppStore with iOS6 SDK?

Big thanks for your replies!

Alexey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Could I build app for AppStore under iOS6 SDK after iOS7 will released (Sept 18)?
```

You can, but I don't know how long.

```
Should (and can) I use XCode 4 for posting to AppStore after iOS7 will released?
```

You may use either XCode 5.0 or XCode 4.6

```
Could I use XCode5 for build app for AppStore with iOS6 SDK?
```

I think you can't.

Comment: You can, but I don't know how long. - Yes, I wonder to know how long firstly. Did you remember how long it was when iOS6 appeared?

Comment: As I remember the issue was not in the SDK, but in iPhone 5 support. The same will be this time, but this time the issue will be in iOS 7 support.